# SQLite database not created

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-device-monitor

I am trying to create a very simple app with three fields and the data should be saved on the SQLite database. When I run the app

1. I get the error message `"Error running app: Instant Run requires "Tools..Android..Enable ADB integration" to be enabled`..
   I did the ADB integration from the menu but everytime I run the app, this error is shown. Do I need to select this option always manually?
2. When I press the button in the app to save the data, the app stops running. I tried to check for the database on the Android Device Monitor but the data folder is not created. I found some related help on this forum and I have done the configuration suggested (see below):

adb shell
su
chmod 777 /data/data/com.example.application.sqliteappl
start the cmd again..
adb root 
adb root –restart

(my package name is: com.example.application.sqliteappl).

I assume that my app stops running because it is not able to create the SQLite Database. **Anyone having a idea how I could resolve this?**

The code in my app is quite simple, I don't think there is any issue:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "MyMessage";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
    public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
//        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABKE IF EXITS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
Log.i( TAG, "onUpgrade()");
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String surname, String marks){
        Log.i(TAG, "insertData()");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contevalues = new ContentValues();

        contevalues.put(COL_2, name);
        contevalues.put(COL_3, surname);
        contevalues.put(COL_4, marks);
       long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contevalues);
if (result == -1)
    return false;
      else
          return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone looking at it.

Regards,

Tarik

Comment: have you tried disabling instant run

Comment: Try to     Invalidate Cache and Restart  Android Studio

Comment: have you  entered `Read and write permission` in `manifest`

Comment: but read and write permission in manifest applies to saving data in files, not in SQLite db...just in case, I still did it and have the same issue..